# change the color of TextView when clicking on Button

Tags: android, button, colors, textview

I have a text box with the title of a book
There is a button next. How can I change the color in the textbox when the button is clicked?

Comment: It might help others help you if you post your existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onClick` method of the button you are using you can something like this:

```
TextView title1 = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
//Your "onclick" method
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        
        title1.setTextColor(Color.MyColor); //changing text color
    }
});
```

Here instead of `myTextView`, use your TextView id. Instead of `MyColor` choose your color, you either have to use the built in colors(i.e. `WHITE`, `BLACK`) or add a color of your own in `values\colors.xml` file with your desired name and use that here.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot to go on, but I'll give it a shot, but first, these are my assumptions:

- By "a text box," you mean a paragraph, div, or other block-level display HTML element showing the title of a book (rather than a textarea or text input containing the editable title of a book, although you could style them, too, if needed).
- By "a button next," you mean that there is a button that a user would perceive as being associated with the book title.

There are lots of ways you could implement this, but here are two very simple ones:

1. You could use the button to trigger a javascript that changes a classname on the element containing the book title with CSS styles that change the appearance of the title when the classname is present or absent.
2. You could use a checkbox (instead of a button element) and use an adjacent (`+`) or successor (`~`) selector to change the style of the title based on the state of the checkbox (`input[type="checkbox"]:checked`), but this requires that the button appear prior to and within the same parent as the book title element.